# How to make a searchIndex in android with java

Tags: java, android, search, lucene

I try make an android app with java and have a problem with searchIndex
I just don't know ho to make it right

I already used lucene in C# but I want to know if I could use it in java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is also a library of Lucene in java and you can use it in android applications.

But there is a native full text search feature called FTS and and also new version FTS4 in SQLite , which you can use in android easily and it has a better performance and response time since its running natively and so much faster because uses less memory than java Lucene impelementation.

You can see a sample here : http://www.mysamplecode.com/2011/11/android-searchview-using-sqlite-fts3.html

and also full documentation here : http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html